# Open application/json type printed in the browser

Tags: jquery, json, http, methods, foursquare

Foursquare's api has the option to search for venues. 
It's an HTTP GET method and has this form:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=40.7,-74&oauth_token=xxxx
```

In Foursquare's example (which is within the api website) works great, shows the array of venues for the given latitude and longitude (40.7,-74) printed in the browser. When I try to use it out of Foursquare here's what happens:

I'm using it like a normal url, I paste it in a browser but instead of showing an array printed in the browser, a download window with the following:

" You have chosen to open -search- which is an application/json type from https://api.foursquare.com. What should the browser do, open it with a program or save it? "

pops up. If I open the file -search- with an editor (or I save it and I open it later) the array is in there.

What am I doing wrong with this? any clues on why I'm not getting the venues array in the browser?

Thanks a million

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing anything wrong. It's just that your computer doesn't have an associated program with the `application/json` content type and thus the browser asks to save it. So save it as a file and you will see the contents of the JSON sent by the server.

Normally an API is supposed to be consumed by a program, so you should not be manually typing this address in a browser => you will be writing an application consuming this API.

Comment: But there's no way to divert the info into the browser? I was thinking in creating a form to help filling the url with the longitude and latitude, in order to make a search of a great number of venues easier. If I have to open a file everytime I do a search, it's better to user the FS api. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I may not have explained myself correctly, I'm still getting json. The solution that worked in my case:

```
   $.ajax({
           url: 'page.php',
           success: function(data) {
         $('.result').html(data);
        // alert('Load was performed.');
           }
         });
```

Thanks a lot